# Function-3D curve on Tikz/PGF

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

So, i am new to Tikz/PGF and i am trying to draw an image showing the change of velocity w.r.t time and distance.

The blue line shows that an object has at first a linear speed up to a point (function υ=χ*τ).
The red line shows that the object decelerates with constant a=1  (function x= υ0t - ½ αt^2) . In my implementation of the deceleration function the red curve **does not move along the axis of time** **t** (or else the axis y), although it changes w.r.t to speed (which should go towards 0) and distance (which grows). What am i doing wrong? Thank you in advance for your tips and solutions!

```
\documentclass[border=45pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture} [ 
    % Define Time with Constant Speed Function 
    declare function={
        linear(\x,\u,\t)= \x / \u;},
     %Define Breaking / Deceleration Function with a=1
    declare function={
        curve(\x,\u,\t)= (\u * \t -(1/2 * 1 * \t^2));}
            ]
    
    \begin{axis}[
        %view={90}{60},
        no markers,
        zmin=0, zmax=10,
        xmin=0, xmax=10,
        ymin=0,ymax=10,
        xtick={3},
        xticklabels={$u_0$},
        ytick={2},
        yticklabels={$t_{safe}$},           
        ztick={6},
        zticklabels={$x_{MP}$},         
        axis lines=middle,
        zlabel=$x$, zlabel style={at={(rel axis cs:0,0,1)}, anchor=east},
        xlabel=$u$, xlabel style={at={(rel axis cs:1,0,0)}, anchor=west},
        ylabel=$t$, ylabel style={at={(rel axis cs:0,1,0)}, anchor=south west}  
         ]



        %dashed Tsafe 
          \draw[dashed] (6,2,0)--(0,2,0); % change middle variable = y to move line on y = t                         axis, also move ticks on above set


       %grayrectangle on Tsafe
        \fill[fill=gray!13,opacity=0.8] (0,2,0) -- (6,2,0) -- (6,2,6) -- (0,2,6) -- (0,2,0); % change middle variable = y to adjust plane on tsafe axis

       %grayrectangle on Xmp
         \fill[fill=gray!15, opacity=0.8] (0,0,6) -- (0,4,6) -- (6,4,6)-- (6,0,6) --   (0,0,6); % if MP point changes, change right variable = z to move plane on z = x axis, also move    ticks on above set

           \addplot3 [blue!50!black, thick,domain=0:1] (3,x, {linear(x,3,0)}); %point         (x,u,t) = (3m,3m/s,1s)
           \addplot3 [red!50!black,thick,domain=0:3] (3-y,1,{curve(3,5,y)});


    
          \end{axis}
         \end{tikzpicture}
       \end{document}
```

Comment: The right-hand side of `curve(\x,\u,\t)= (\u * \t -(1/2 * 1 * \t^2));` does not depend on `\x`. It seems to be `x(t)` for some initial velocity `\dot x(0)=\u`. It is also not really a deceleration in the usual sense.

Comment: So what should i do to make it move along the y axis ? I tried to implement the \x but it doesn't yield any results

Comment: The y-dependence, i.e. the dependence in direction of the of the second direction which is labeled `t`, of the plot is governed of `\addplot3 [red!50!black,thick,domain=0:3] (3-y,1,{curve(3,5,y)});` by the second component, which you set to `1`. Note that we may misunderstand each other because I do not know what you mean by y-dependence, which has two interpretations in the way you set up things.

Comment: Thank you both guys! Found it. As "anonymous" mentioned, i changed the ,1, (before {curve...} to ,y+1, and it worked. Thank you once again!